# Suggestions for hosting SPA on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application that has an Angular Frontend and a Django Backend. I've already set up my django application to run on Elastic beanstalk, however, I am unsure what I should do to serve static files. I'd rather not handle this within the django application.

I have tried using nginx reverse proxy with elastic beanstalk to properly serve files, however I'm unable to serve them on "/", only extensions like "/index" or "/dashboard", and the js files the index.html needs aren't found (404 error).

I thought about rewriting the entire nginx configuration but I'm unsure where to start. Any ideas would be very helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your Angular frontend on S3 (with website hosting enabled). To make it more performant and cheap, add CloudFront in front of it. Different paths (APIs) of your application can be routed to backend via CloudFront "Behaviours" feature. You can set No-Caching for those dynamic paths.

Reference:
https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef

Comment: Thanks. Can the S3 frontend and django backend be configured under the same URL?

Comment: Yes it can be. You should set the URL / Domain on CloudFront as CNAME and set the behaviours accordingly. APIs / dynamic content will use no-cache and static / angular app should set some cache. 2 origins multiple behaviours in CloudFront.

Comment: Thx. I ended up doing something slightly different but this is a very nice solution.